# How to import ldapjs into EmberJS

Tags: node.js, ember.js

I have an EmberJS application, that authenticates users using an LDAP account. Now, as per [ldapjs documentation](http://ldapjs.org/client.html), i could simple create a ldap-client using the below code.

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var client = ldap.createClient({
  url: 'ldap://127.0.0.1:1389'
});
```

But, i am getting a `"require is not defined"` error in the first line. On googling, i found that the `require()` can only be used from server and not from client.

How should i import and use the ldapjs here ?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, *require()* is not the proper way to import packages in an Ember application.

Please read the ember-cli guide to see how you can import third party code in your Emmber application. https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#managing-dependencies

However, *ldapjs* seems to me to be a server side only library. I fail to see why you would like a LDAP server on your frontend.
If you are looking to use parts of ldapjs to work with a LDAP server, take a look at browserify and its ember plugin (https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify). This will allow you to `require` a module in an Ember app.

Comment: I wont be sure about ldapjs being server-side library. I have seen a working AngularJS application, which uses ldapjs for authentication. I assume AngularJS and EmberJS are both client-side framework.

Comment: I understand now. You can use ember-browserify to do this. See my updated answer.

Comment: Using ember-browserify did solve the issue. But, now i am getting some error from within the "ldapjs" library. I assume all the "ldapjs" dependecies were also imported by "ember-browserify" and the error has nothing to do with "ember-browserify". I will check that and update.

Comment: To my knowledge, browserify also bundles the dependencies. You might be able to use the browser JavaScript debugger to check on this error.